# how to hide or show an element depending on radio button state?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

in this laravel blade I have a form which has two radio buttons `local` and `global` and a dropdown `select`, what I want to do is, by default the dropdown select is hidden(invisible) and global radio is checked and the dropdown select should be visible only by ticking internal radio button.

global radio checked -> dropdown select invisible(default)

internal radio checked -> dropdown select visible.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <p>Type:</p>
     <input  name="type" type="radio" id="internal" value="internal" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;">
     <label for="internal">internal</label><br>
     <input  name="type" type="radio" id="global" value="global"  style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;" checked>
     <label for="global">global</label>
                                                
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="company_select" >
                                                
     <label for="company"> Company </label>
     <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
         <option  value="company_id.1">company1</option>
         <option  value="company_id.2">company2</option>
     </select> 
                                                     
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Comment: You can achieve with css so don't need to write javascript code for show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another simple implementation. By default the the select is hidden (using css). Then Use change event for radio and simply check the value of
`$("#internal")` is checked and decide to show of hide

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input[name=type]").change(function(){

        if($("#internal").is(':checked')){
            $("#company_select").show();
        }else{
            $("#company_select").hide();
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <p>Type:</p>
     <input  name="type" type="radio" id="internal" value="internal" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;">
     <label for="internal">internal</label><br>
     <input  name="type" type="radio" id="global" value="global"  style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;" checked>
     <label for="global">global</label>
                                                
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="company_select" style="display:none">
                                                
     <label for="company"> Company </label>
     <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company" >
         <option  value="company_id.1">company1</option>
         <option  value="company_id.2">company2</option>
     </select> 
                                                     
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, the missing thing is that when first the page is rendered the global radio is checked but the select dropdown is visible, it became invisible when I click on internal and again on global and thats right, but I want the first default for the select to be invisible with global checked

Comment: The code that i have posted is same, first the default is global selected and the select is also invisble, did i miss something?

Comment: no your answer is right and I accepted it, I just didn't use css to hide selecet at first, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if` statement to check if your checked radio input's value is `internal` or not, then hide or show your select.

```js
function toggleSelectDropdown() {
  const radioButton = $('.form-group-radios input[type="radio"]');
  const selectElem = $('select');
  
  radioButton.on('change', (e) => {
    const self = $(e.currentTarget);
    const value = self.val();
    
    // Check if the checked radio button's value is internal, then show the select
    if (value == "internal") {
      selectElem.show();
      return false;
    }
    
    // If not, then hide it.
    selectElem.hide();
  });
}

toggleSelectDropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group form-group-radios">
     <p>Type:</p>
     <input  name="type" type="radio" id="internal" value="internal" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;" checked>
     <label for="internal">internal</label><br>
     <input  name="type" type="radio" id="global" value="global"  style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;">
     <label for="global">global</label>
                                                
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="company_select" >
                                                
     <label for="company"> Company </label>
     <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
         <option  value="company_id.1">company1</option>
         <option  value="company_id.2">company2</option>
     </select> 
                                                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event click listener to the radios and create two style for hide and show, then toggle these class depend on radio checked.

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('type');
radios.map((radio, index) => {
  radio.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    const selectClass = document.getElementById('company_select').classList;
    if (ev.target.checked && ev.target.value === 'internal') {
      if (selectClass?.contains('hide')) selectClass.remove('hide')
      selectClass?.add('show')
    } else if (ev.target.checked && ev.target.value === 'global') {
      if (selectClass?.contains('show')) selectClass.remove('show')
      selectClass?.add('hide')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <p>Type:</p>
  <input name="type" type="radio" id="internal" value="internal" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;">
  <label for="internal">internal</label><br>
  <input name="type" type="radio" id="global" value="global" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;" checked>
  <label for="global">global</label>

</div>
<div class="form-group" id="company_select">

  <label for="company"> Company </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
    <option value="company_id.1">company1</option>
    <option value="company_id.2">company2</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code does no work. 1. Do not use a map when you need a forEach 2. there is no .map available to the collection returned from getElementsByName. Use forEach and querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 0):

Working version using hidden

Plain JS

```js
const radioContainer = document.getElementById('radioContainer');
const selContainer = document.getElementById('company_select');

radioContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('[name=type]')) return; // not a radio
  selContainer.hidden = tgt.value === 'internal';
});
selContainer.hidden = document.querySelector('[name=type][checked]').value === 'internal';
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="radioContainer">
  <p>Type:</p>
  <label><input name="type" type="radio" id="internal" value="internal" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;"> internal</label><br>
  <label><input name="type" type="radio" id="global" value="global" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;" checked> global</label>

</div>
<div class="form-group" id="company_select" hidden>
  <label for="company"> Company </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
    <option value="company_id.1">company1</option>
    <option value="company_id.2">company2</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

jQuery

```js
const $sel = $('#company_select')
  .toggle($('[name=type]:checked').val() === 'global');

$('#radioContainer').on('click', '[name=type]', function() {
  $sel.toggle(this.value === 'global');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="radioContainer">
  <p>Type:</p>
  <label><input name="type" type="radio" id="internal" value="internal" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;"> internal</label><br>
  <label><input name="type" type="radio" id="global" value="global" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor: pointer;" checked> global</label>

</div>
<div class="form-group" id="company_select" hidden>
  <label for="company"> Company </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
    <option value="company_id.1">company1</option>
    <option value="company_id.2">company2</option>
  </select>

</div>
```